# Use of Start-job for WatcherChangeTypes

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to monitor the file changes in the directory in the powershell background.

I was trying to do as below.

```
 Start-Job {
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = get-location
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite -bor [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

    while($true){
        $result = $watcher.WaitForChanged([System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Changed -bor [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Renamed -bOr [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Created, 1000);
        if($result.TimedOut){
            continue;
        }
    Add-Content D:\receiver.txt "file name is $($result.Name)"
    }
}
```

This does not work as expected. I do not get any information on the receiver.txt file. Although the script works as expected if I dont use start-job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-Job` will launch your job in a new context, so the working directory will be the default directory (e.g. `\Users\Username`) and `Get-Location` will return this directory.

One way to deal with this is to save the original working directory, pass it to the job as an argument, and set the working directory *in the job* using `Set-Location`.

```
$currentLocation = Get-Location
Start-Job -ArgumentList $currentLocation {
   Set-Location $args[0];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Register-ObjectEvent and track each event type. It uses the same PSJobs that you would use in Start-Job, but geared towards monitoring the actual event and running a specific action based on what you give it.

Not tested:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = get-location
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite -bor [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName
ForEach ($Item in @('Changed','Renamed','Created')) {
    (Register-ObjectEvent -EventName $Item -InputObject $watcher -Action {
        #Set up a named mutex so there are no errors accessing an opened file from another process
        $mtx = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex($false, "FileWatcher")
        $mtx.WaitOne()
        Add-Content D:\receiver.txt "file name is $($result.Name)" 
        #Release so other processes can write to file
        [void]$mtx.ReleaseMutex()
    })
}
```

Quick way to stop the FileSystemWatcher

```
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force
```